# storing in app purchase information on user's device

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, client-side

I have read the apple guide for in app purchase and im wondering instead of having an external server to store user's in app purchase like extra-content-unlocks, can I store the information on the user device?

What implication is there if I store purchased extra-content-unlocks on user's device?

Is there any way to avoid having an external server to store user's purchased extra-content-unlocks information

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have an external service but you cannot rely on the device to faithfully verify in app purchase receipts. This might be totally acceptable if forged purchases have a negligible cost to you. If you incur an expense for each purchase or need to verify them for some other reason (for example preventing users for reporting high scores on levels they have not purchased) then you may need an external service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let's say my game sells new levels. New levels bought will be downloaded from Game Center. Can I rely on user device to remember which levels are purchased and which levels are not?

Comment: Not exactly. You do not need to store the purchases on your own server however you are required to implement a "restore purchases" option so that users can re-fetch their purchase receipts from the App Store (in case they delete and reinstall the app, replace their device, install the app on a second device, and so on). I think Apple's docs cover this pretty well.